# Issue in making disabled checkbox enabled false

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function checkenabledisable() {
  if ($("#completebatch").is(':checked')) {
    $('.commoncheckbox').prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $('.commoncheckbox').prop("checked", false);
  }

  $('.disabled-check').removeAttr("checked");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input onclick="checkenabledisable()" id="completebatch" type="checkbox"></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check" type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The checkbox inside table header is used to check all and uncheck all the checkboxes in table body. The above code check all the checkboxes. I want that it should check all those checkboxes which do not has class "disabled-check". The above code check those checkboxes also... Please help!!!

Comment: Your code is working fine

Comment: no it is checking all the checkboxes... please help me if there is any other way to make disabled checkboxes unchecked...

Comment: What you are looking for is `$('.commoncheckbox:not(.disabled-check)').prop(...)`

Comment: To all the people who are getting mislead, OP has disabled that checkbox. Hence its not getting selected. But the objective is to have a quetySelector/approach that would filter such elements out irrespective of disabled state

Answer (score 2):

your code is fine except last line which should be

```
$('.disabled-check').removeProp("checked"); // this is property not attribute
```

But you can try below solution too.
you can directly bind change event handler to check all checkbox and put its value to all checkboxes with `is(":checked")` and put `.not(".disabled-check")` to exclude these checkebox

```js
$(function(){
  $("#completebatch").on("change", function(){
    $('.commoncheckbox').not(".disabled-check").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<thead>
  <th><input id="completebatch" type="checkbox"></th>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check" type="checkbox" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td><input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td><input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Just for demo purpose, you can remove that `disabled` attr so its visible in snippet